# ensuring PHP good coding practice with functions?

Tags: php, redirect, verification

I'm relatively new to PHP, and I want to ensure I code as efficiently and as correctly I can - specifically, I'd like to ask about how functions should be implemented with each other and how large and how many tasks they each should do under optimal conditions.

### Example

For the sake of an example (and possibly something I will need to implement), say there is link to a page which reads "forgotten your username/password?", upon clicking this link, they are brought to a page `forgot.php`, which has two forms on it:

1) If they've forgotten their **password**, they enter their **username**, and a link to a reset form is sent to their **email address**.

2) And another is if they've forgotten their **username**, they enter their **email address**, and this is sent to them via their **email address** .

Upon clicking submit, the relevant form is `$_POST`'ed to a new page called `forgotsubmit.php`, which checks if it is being accessed legitimately through an `if` statement:

```
//loggedIn() is a previously defined function

if (!loggedIn() && isset($_POST['forgotUsername']) || isset($_POST['forgotPassword'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

Otherwise, the page will run normally, and that is: start a function(s), and display a message telling the user to check their email. How I would implement/create the function(s) necessary for this to occur.

#### Possibility One - 1 function

Should there be a single, large, function that is called that can handle both forgotten passwords and usernames, through an if statement inside the function, then create a query fetching the relevant fields of data from a MySQL databse, organize and then `strip_tags()` all the data, send an email containing the necessary information, and then echo a success/failure back depending on what form was chosen and whether the code completed without errors?

#### Possibility Two - 2 functions

Have an if statement on `forgotsubmit.php` which determines which function to run - one to fetch a username, and another to reset the password, each doing what was described in possibilty one.

#### Possibility Three - a handful of functions

The same as possibility two, except a separate sendMail() function could send out the email, another function could handle the MySQL queries, etc.

Does calling too many functions slow performance? Is the (if any) performance loss made up by the time cost of not having to code sending mail twice, for example?

#### Possibility Four - dozens of functions, no functions, something else entirely?

Could I be using something better for a task like this? Would multiple functions be appropriate? I have heard of classes, but haven't looked into them, would they be appropriate?

### Summary

I hope I have made myself concise enough. As I understand (or have read), the job of a function is to 'make repetitive processes simple', perhaps one of these possibilities would fulfill that task. How would you code it? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe send every form to a separate file? `forgotpassword.php` and `forgotusername.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It completely depends on the task on your hand. Its always better to have some functions like `do_this()`, `do_that()` instead `do_all_stuff()`.

For me I follow a general rule. **Each time I end up need a code block I wrote earlier, I convert it to a function**. If you follow this rule, you'll end up creating lots of re-usable functions. Also the code will automatically be refactoring.

Answer (score 4):

No matter what programming paradigm or language you're using, there's a good rule saying that **a function should only do one thing**. It makes your code more readable and easier to maintain, and has the additional benefit of allowing more code re-use.

Comment: good point @manu. a mentor told me once that if your function is several screens high it might be time to consider refactoring it by breaking it up into smaller functions.

Answer (score 2):

Even though PHP was built for the web, one thing it lacks is a good architecture for building an entire web application. Out of the box, you get single file scripts that don't have any architected lines of communication with one another.

I highly reccomend using a framework. Zend Framework is a good choice, but there are dozens of others. The conventions they use will answer most of your questions, as they will outline what files need to be created, what functions go where, and give you a way to wire everything together.

Some frameworks:

- [Zend Framework](http://www.zendframework.com)
- [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org)
- [Code Igniter](http://codeigniter.com)
- [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org)

Comment: Suggesting the use of a framework is a great idea, but the OP seems to be a beginner in PHP, so I suppose it may be a bit premature.

Comment: @ManuLetroll I'm not so sure I agree. With PHP's disjointed nature, it may be easier for a beginner to follow along with a framework's documentation and examples to produce something workable rather than trying to piece it together themselves.

Comment: I'm all for using frameworks. The only issue I saw was for a beginner in programming in general. Frameworks usually require you to grasp a number of concepts which, I suppose, are not always easy to learn for a complete beginner.
That said, I found CodeIgniter to quite good as a first PHP framework, easy to learn thanks to its excellent documentation.

Comment: @ManuLetroll I see where you are coming from. My hope would be that the additional framework specific documentation would provide enough examples to actually accelerate the learning process. Additionally, a framework takes away decisions such as the ones the OP is asking about to begin with. Once those issues are removed, OP can focus on actually creating something which would serve to remove some of the frustration from the learning process. It's hard to think like a beginner again, however, and you may be right in that it's too much too soon.